# How to adjust the range into iteration for if some rows are deleted

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I have a dataframe with 12.675 rows at the begining.

```
Proyectonevera2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  Int64Index: 12689 entries, 3 to 12683
   Data columns (total 60 columns):
```

But I need to go over all the dataframe and delete some rows according some operation into there:

```
for i in range(0,len(Proyectonevera2)-1):
if Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Clave'] == "P":
    CodIng = Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Ingrediente']
    NuevoInv_Ing = Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Nuevo Inventario']
    for j in range(0,len(Proyectonevera2)-1):
        if Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Clave'] == "N":
            Codprod = Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'CodProducto']
            if Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Ingrediente'] == CodIng:
                Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Inv_Ing'] = NuevoInv_Ing
                if Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Cant Ingr SUM'] !=0 and Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Cant Prod SUM']!=0:
                    Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Cantidad producir']=Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Inv_Ing']*Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Cant Prod SUM']/Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Cant Ingr SUM']
                    dfc = Proyectonevera2.groupby('CodProducto')['Cantidad producir']
                    Proyectonevera2.assign(min=dfc.transform(min))
                    Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Consumo Agosto'] = Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'min']*Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Cant Ingr SUM']/Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Cant Prod SUM']
                    Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Nuevo Inventario'] = Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Inv_Ing']-Proyectonevera2.loc[j,'Consumo Agosto']
                    Proyectonevera2= Proyectonevera2.drop(Proyectonevera2[Proyectonevera2['Clave']=="P"].index)
                    Proyectonevera2 = Proyectonevera2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

And the output that I have gotten is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    384                 try:
--> 385                     return self._range.index(new_key)
    386                 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: 12675 is not in range
```

This is because at the begining the len of dataframe were 12.675 rows but if I delete some rows the len will be less, so I need to arrange in this part, to adjust the len

```
for i in range(0,len(Proyectonevera2)-1):
```

How can I manage it?

Comment: First of all you shouldn't iterate through a range.  Instead `for row in Proyectonevera2:` to access the row.  If you need the index in addition to the row then use enumerate `for i, row in enumerate(Proyectonevera2):` will give you the index and the row.

Comment: It can help if you iterate over the dataframe backwards like `for j in range(len(Proyectonevera2)-2, -1, -1):`, so you won't face the problem with no more existing indices, BUT ... it would be a much better idea to save the indices to rows which should be deleted while looping over the rows of the dataframe and delete them later on in one separate command (or in a loop) as deleting rows while looping over iterable items had side-effects you should strictly avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not C or other language that you have to worry about figuring out the range before iterating.  Instead just iterate through the iterable directly.  This allows you to iterate even if you don't know the size and prevents many off-by-one errors and an iterable changing size while processing.

So instead of:

```
for i in range(data):
    item = data[i]
    # do something with item
```

Do the following:

```
for item in data:
    # do something with item
```

If you do need the index as well, then you can use enumerate as follows:

```
for index, item in enumerate(data):
    # do something with item and/or index
```

Comment: The above recommendations even if eventually helpful in avoiding index value errors will have side-effects of skipping items of the iterable from processing in the loop in case deleting of iterable items (rows of Pandas dataframes) is part of the data processing.

Answer (score -1):

The advice given in the answer of *Brian M. Sheldon* does not cover the case of deleting rows/items of the iterable as part of their processing and will lead to side-effects of not visited rows/items and/or rising an index out of range error.

Generally it is a very bad idea to delete items/rows in a loop while processing the iterable data.

**A good idea is to remember while processing the indices of the items/rows for later deletion.** Pandas allow to delete multiple rows at once if provided with a list with their indices.

As a quick (not recommended) fix before restructuring the code in the question to separate processing and deleting of data could be looping over the dataframe backwards from the end to the start:

```
for j in range(len(Proyectonevera2)-2, -1, -1):
```

in order to get the error with not available indices out of the way.

But *please* put considerably effort into separating as good as possible deleting of items from their processing bearing in mind the danger of hard to track and to detect side-effects. *And if possible use looping over items/rows and not over indices* ( with `for row in Proyectonevera2:` or `for indx, row in enumerate(Proyectonevera2):`).

Let's give here only one bare minimal example of a side-effect using a small list instead of a pandas dataframe to make it as simple as possible to see the reason for the advice to separate content deletion from processing it in a loop.

**The example below demonstrates that if deleting of items is involved Python `for item in iterable:` loop will silently not 'visit' all of the items of the iterable.**

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4]
for value in lst:
    print(f' > {value=}, {lst.index(value)=} {lst=}', end=' ')
    if value==1:
        lst.pop(lst.index(0)) # delete value 0 from list
        lst.pop(lst.index(1)) # delete value 1 from list
    if value==2:
        lst[lst.index(2)]='2' # change value from 2 to '2'
    if value==3:
        lst[lst.index(3)]='3' # change value from 3 to '3'
    try:               lst_index_value = lst.index(value)
    except ValueError: lst_index_value = None
    print(f' >> {value=}, lst.index(value)={lst_index_value} {lst=}')
print(f'  FINALLY: {lst=} WHERE values 2 and 3 were not "visited" in the loop' )
```

printing:

```
 > value=0, lst.index(value)=0 lst=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  >> value=0, lst.index(value)=0 lst=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 > value=1, lst.index(value)=1 lst=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  >> value=1, lst.index(value)=None lst=[2, 3, 4]
 > value=4, lst.index(value)=2 lst=[2, 3, 4]  >> value=4, lst.index(value)=2 lst=[2, 3, 4]
  FINALLY: lst=[2, 3, 4] WHERE  values 2 and 3 were not "visited" in the loop
```

Comment: While you are correct in your assertion that my answer might not visit all branches, my method will never lead to an index out of range error.  My answer was intended to be agnostic to the actual processing performed as I feel those types of answers tend to be more useful to the community as a whole.

Comment: It can be a bad idea to delete items while iterating, but it can be equally problematic doing it outside of the iteration if you're not careful.  For example if a person were to use a naive implementation of deleting each item by its index without starting from the end they could accidentally delete desired data.